# Change Making algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

A typical Change Making problem but a bit twisted. Given a large amount and the denominations given, I need to come up with total number of ways in which the amount can be made using RECURSION. The signature of the function is as follows

`int makeChange(int Amount, int[] Denominations)`

Amount-Total Amount

Denominations- The available denominatins.

It returns total number of ways.. make sure this has to be  done Using Recursion..

Comment: If the amount is `5` and denominations is `[5, 2, 1]`, are `1, 1, 1, 2` and `2, 1, 1, 1` equivalent or different?

Comment: @SimeonVisser They are the same.. the denominations would be 221 1112 5 so function should return 3.

Comment: There is also 1,1,1,1,1 - the example should return 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key idea is to understand at each point you have two choices:

1. Use the current coin you are looking at, and recurse when decreasing it from `amount`.
2. Don't use it, and make it unavailable for later selection.

The function should return the summation of (1) and (2).

Pseudo-code:

```
makeChange(amount,Denominations):
   //stop clauses:
   if (amount == 0) return 1
   if (amount < 0) return 0
   i <- first index of Denominations where Denominations[i] is not zero
   if there is no such i (all are zero):
        return 0
   num1 = makeChange(amount-Denominations[i],Denominations) //recursive call, using Denominations[i]
   temp <- Denominations[i]
   Denominations[i] = 0
   num2 = makeChange(amount,Denominations) //recursive call, not using Denominations[i] - and will never do again
   Denominations[i] = temp //setting environment back to original
   return num1+num2
```

java code:

```
public static int makeChange(int amount, int[] d) { 
    if (amount < 0) return 0;
    if (amount == 0) return 1;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) { 
        if (d[i] != 0) break;
    }
    if (i == d.length) return 0;
    int num1 = makeChange(amount-d[i],d);
    int temp = d[i];
    d[i] = 0;
    int num2 = makeChange(amount,d);
    d[i] = temp;
    return num1 + num2;
}
```